# A circle/icon for each entry in CSV

Tags: extjs, d3.js

Basically what I have is a csv file with first column as name of an item, and second column as type of that item. There are only 3 types.

```
id      type  ....
item1   t1
item2   t2
item3   t1
item4   t3
```

and I would like to display a circle or an icon for each type. Lets say a box(rectangle) for t1 which contains circles for item1 and item3. Below that another box for t2 and same for t3.

Further I would like to do some other actions by clicking on the 'item' circles.

(I'm completely noob for this stuff and searches could not find any relevant answers)

Answer (score 0):

For icon

```
 d3.selectAll("g.node")
 .data(dataCSV)
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .attr("class", "node")

 .text(function(d) {
     return (d.type === "t1") ? ":)" : (d.type === "t2") ? ";)" : ":(";
 })
```

If you need `circle` then replace `text` to `circle` syntax.

Comment: I've used for and if else to achieve the objective. Thanks anyways :)